# No longer running a gnome-session; how do I get the nice GTK theme back?

Tags: gnome, gtk

I changed my desktop environment (I forget exactly how) to remove the gnome panels and instead I'm using xmonad and xmobar and just terminal windows and so on.  It seems I'm no longer running in a gnome-session, however, and the GTK themes don't load.  If I run the `gnome-settings-daemon` it fixes this.  What's the best way to get the daemon to run on startup so I have the nice themes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about if this is an efficient way to achieve this.

using crontab, there is a way to run commands on startup

```
crontab -e
    @reboot gnome-settings-daemon
```

[crontab how to](http://ubuntu-for-humans.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/using-crontab-in-ubuntu.html)